# How can I make use of Saramäki and MATLAB implementation of the Remez multiple exchange algorithm for FIR filter design

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters, parks-mclellan

Seeking assistance with an optimized and well-documented implementation of the Parks-McClellan algorithm, I explored beyond the original FORTRAN code provided in [A Computer Program for Designing Optimum FIR Linear Phase Digital Filter](https://web.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/062_computer%20program.pdf).

Instead, I discovered other available options such as an open-source C implementation, which was essentially a direct translation of the FORTRAN version. Further research led me to uncover texts like [Two Novel Implementations of the Remez Multiple Exchange Algorithm for Optimum FIR Filter Design](https://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/39374/InTech-Two_novel_implementations_of_the_remez_multiple_exchange_algorithm_for_optimum_fir_filter_design.pdf) and [A MATLAB based optimum multiband FIR filters design program following the original idea of the Remez multiple exchange algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221375897_A_MATLAB_based_optimum_multiband_FIR_filters_design_program_following_the_original_idea_of_the_Remez_multiple_exchange_algorithm) These programs assumes to be an enhanced version of original code, resulting in significantly faster execution times.

I'm encountering two main issues:

1. I've struggled to utilize the algorithm effectively to generate an FIR filter of an order higher than approximately 700.
2. I'm uncertain whether I'm correctly implementing the code.

**Note:** *I understand that the Remez implementation doesn't directly provide the impulse response. Moreover, I am aware of the necessity to adjust the desired magnitude response and weight function based on the filter type (symmetry and length). Any guidance on this aspect would be greatly appreciated.*

Currently, my code usage resembles the following:

```matlab
% the number of indices in the alternation set (keep even?)
nz = 1000;
% resolution of the frequency grid
ngrid = nz * 20;
% frequency grid (length ngrid)
grid = (0:ngrid-1).*(0.5/ngrid);
% indices of extremal frequencies (length nz)
iext = round(linspace(1, ngrid, nz));
% desired amplitude response
nyq = 0.5;
fpass = 0.45*nyq; fstop = 0.55*nyq; fcut = (fpass + fstop)/2;
des = (grid <= fcut);
% weight function
Kp = 1.5; Ks = 3.5;
wt = (grid<=fpass).*Kp +(grid>=fstop).*Ks;
wt = wt + 0.3;
[x,y,ad,dev]=remez_imp1(nz, iext, ngrid, grid, des, wt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

700 coefficients seems a high number for `remez`.

[If I try using Matlab's design tools](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/minimax-fir-filter-design.html), it seems get numerical problems between 300 and 350 coefficients.

[image: Error from Matlab]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, resources on this topic are hard to find. I have read that the Parks-McClellan algorithm is the best for designing high order FIR filters. I have a program that I wrote that makes least-squares optimal FIR filters in orders of 20000+. Also, what is the difference between MATLAB's f"irpm()" and the one you use "firgr()"?

Comment: Yes, least squares optimal filters are much better behaved numerically than minimax designs like Remez.